# If $f:\ V\longrightarrow V $ is nilpotent and $a\ne0$, then $\big|[f]-aI_n\big|\ne0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space and $f:\ V \longrightarrow V$ a nilpotent linear operator. Given $a\ne0$, then $\big|[f]-aI_n\big|\ne0$.

My proof :

Since $f$ is nilpotent, there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f^n=0$. Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ and $v\ne0$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector. We have
$$0\,=\,f^n(v)\,=\,\lambda^nv $$
this implies $\lambda^n=0$, thus $\lambda=0$.

Suppose $\big|[f]-aI_n\big|=0$, then $a$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, hence $a=0$, a contradiction. Therefore $\big|[f]-aI_n\big|\ne0$.

But I'm not quite sure about the argument $\big|[f]-aI_n\big|=0$ implies $a$ is eigenvalue. What do you think about my proof? Can I do differently in some part? Thanks.

Comment: What does $[f]$ mean?

Comment: If $[f]$ denotes the matrix of $f$ with respect to some bases, and $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$ denotes the determinant of a matrix, then I think the argument follows from the definition of eigenvalue.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio in the last line I deduce that $a=0$, but the hypothesis states that $a\ne0$, so this is a contradiction

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio i see it, so I think I should say $V$ is a real vector space, so we have every linear operator on $V$ will admits an eigenvalue, right ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio how about $V$ is vector space over $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think I want to know if my proof is correct for the given assumptions, but I think I may clarify more information about the vector space $V$, since in my course, $V$ is always assumed to be a real vector space, or sometimes a complex vector space.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known fact that the roots of the polynomial

$$ p(\lambda ) = \det(A - \lambda I)$$
are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$. In fact this is sometimes taken as the definition of an eigenvalue.

Indeed if $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$, then it follows that $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible and you can deduce that the equation $(A- \lambda I)v = 0$ has non trivial solutions. That is, there exists $v \neq 0$ such that

$$ (A-\lambda I) v = 0 \iff Av = \lambda v.$$

Comment: but what if $\big|A-\lambda I\big|=0$ has no solution in $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Let $A = [f]$ and suppose that $a \neq 0$ such that $\vert A - a I \vert = 0$. Then the equation  $\vert A - a I \vert = 0$ tells us that $a$ is an eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix. From your post we know this means that $a$ must therefore be equal to $0$.  But this is impossible since we assumed at the start that $a \neq 0$.

Hence $a \neq 0 \implies \vert A - a I\vert \neq 0.$

What happens in the specific case where $\vert A - \lambda I \vert = 0$ has no real solution is kind of irrelevant to the given problem.

Comment: Moreover in general $\vert A - \lambda I \vert = 0$ always has the solution $ \lambda = 0$ when $A$ is nilpotent since the determinant of a nilpotent matrix is always $0$. This is because $A^n = 0 \implies \vert A \vert^n = 0 \implies \vert A \vert = 0.$

Comment: I see it, thanks.